# SelectionChanged get Textblock Text/ID

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, selectionchanged, navigationservice

I have som listbox and i need som help to get text from x:Name="ThisID" on SelectionChanged.

I've did something like (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem but more than that, I do not know how to do.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"  x:Name="ListBoxD" SelectionChanged="ListBoxD_SelectionChanged" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Margin="10,0,0,0">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
<Border Width="80" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Margin="0,5,0,0" Padding="5,0,5,10">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeliveryNumber}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="72" />
 </Border>
 <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelD" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0,0,0">
     <TextBlock x:Name="ThisID" Text="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
     <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="23" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding AddressLine}"/>                               
  </StackPanel>

</StackPanel></DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

private void ListBoxDeliveryTo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page.xaml?ID=" + ID, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your `ListBox` is bound to a collection of items that are of type `MyCustomItem`, which have the following properties: `DeliveryNumber`, `ID`, `Name` (as I can tell from your `DataTemplate`).

When `SelectionChanged` happens, you are, in fact, able to directly retrieve the item that was selected:

```
MyCustomItem item = (MyCustomItem)lstItems.SelectedItem;
```

Then, you can just get its name. Make sure to check whether the selected item is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Lets try this In FirstPage.xamal if U have some Code like this

```
 <ListBox x:Name="FirstListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="FirstListBox_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <StackPanel>
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
                      </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate></ListBox>
```

And in Firtpage.xaml.cs

```
     private void FirstListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/newmessage.xaml?selectedItem=" + FirstListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
        FirstListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Now go to Secondpage.xaml

in Grid 
Add this

```
 <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Data}" />
```

in Secondpage.xaml.cs Add this code

```
    int index = 0;
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        string selectedIndex = "";
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
        {
            index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);
            DataContext = App.ViewModel.Items[index];
        }
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    }
```